# Including node modules in AWS Lambda

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, lambda

I am trying to create a nodejs lambda function with the web3 module.

However, when zipping my handler.js and the entire node_modules directory and testing the lambda, the function cannot find web3.

Structure of the zip file:

```
handler.js
node_modules/
-web3_module_1/
-web3_module_2/
-other_modules_used_by_web3/
```

According to this [source](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-create-deployment-pkg.html), the zip file structure should be the following:

```
handler.js
web3_module_1/
web3_module_2/
other_module/
```

But even with this structure, I get an error:

```
Unable to import module 'handler': Error
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/task/handler.js:3:14)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
```

What is the correct way to achieve this?

Comment: The first structure is the correct one. You should have `node_modules` in there. The second structure is wrong. Your "source" actually indicates the first one as the correct structure.

Comment: 1st structure is correct. Make sure you are zipping it correctly. You can see the structure in Lambda interface now. Make sure it is consistent with the 1st structure.